# Why doesn't my Elastic Enterprise search configuration work?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm trying to set up a deployment of [Elastic Enterprise Search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/enterprise-search/current/index.html) now that it's free as part of the standard license. For the life of me, I can't get the service to see our Elasticsearch cluster, and I can't figure out why.

I have a configuration file that looks like this:

```
elasticsearch.ssl.enabled: true
elasticsearch.ssl.verify: false

ent_search.auth.source: standard

secret_management.encryption_keys: [secret]

allow_es_settings_modification: true

elasticsearch.host: https://monitoring.internal
elasticsearch.username: elastic
elasticsearch.password: secret
```

When I separately try to use `curl` to access the resource from the sever where I'm trying to run the service, it works just fine:

```
$ curl --user elastic:secret https://monitoring.internal -k
{
  "name" : "monitoring-es-client-0",
  "cluster_name" : "monitoring",
  "cluster_uuid" : "XXX",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.9.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "a479a2a7fce0389512d6a9361301708b92dff667",
    "build_date" : "2020-08-11T21:36:48.204330Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.6.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

But when I try to run the Enterprise Search service, it fails to completely boot up with the unhelpful error message:

```
[2020-09-16T20:25:21.546+00:00][42859][2002][app-server][INFO]: Failed to connect to Elasticsearch backend. Make sure it is running.
```

And the diagnostic report function isn't much more helpful:

```
$ sudo bin/enterprise-search --diagnostic-report
Found java executable in PATH
Java version detected: 11.0.8 (major version: 11)
Enterprise Search is starting...
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.headius.backport9.modules.Modules (file:/usr/share/enterprise-search/lib/war/lib/jruby-core-9.2.9.0-complete.jar) to method sun.nio.ch.NativeThread.signal(long)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.headius.backport9.modules.Modules
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[2020-09-16T20:29:50.258+00:00][43020][2002][script][INFO]: Enterprise Search version=7.9.1, JRuby version=9.2.9.0, Ruby version=2.5.7, Rails version=4.2.11.3
[2020-09-16T20:29:51.158+00:00][43020][2002][script][INFO]: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[2020-09-16T20:29:51.160+00:00][43020][2002][script][ERROR]: 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Error: Enterprise Search is unable to connect to Elasticsearch. Ensure a healthy Elasticsearch cluster is running at https://monitoring.internal for user elastic.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What am I doing wrong in my configuration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting this same error.  I was able to have Enterprise-search talk to the elasticsearch database by enabling the following settings in the
config/enterprise-search.yml file.

I had a PKCS12 truststore and used the following commands to extract the files I needed:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in elasticsearch-certificates.p12 -out outfile.crt -nokeys
openssl pkcs12 -in elasticsearch-certificates.p12 -out outfile.key -nodes -nocerts
openssl pkcs12 -in elasticsearch-certificates.p12 -cacerts -nokeys -out ca.crt
```

I also used chown enterprise-search:enterprise-search on these files for good measure.

```
elasticsearch.ssl.enabled: true
elasticsearch.ssl.certificate: "/usr/share/enterprise-search/outfile.crt"
elasticsearch.ssl.certificate_authority: "/usr/share/enterprise-search/ca.crt"
elasticsearch.ssl.key: "/usr/share/enterprise-search/outfile.key"
elasticsearch.ssl.key_passphrase: [key password]
elasticsearch.ssl.verify: false
```

You'll also need an SSL certificate for the Enterprise Search website to load

```
ent_search.ssl.enabled: true
ent_search.ssl.keystore.path: "/home/<user>/http.p12"
ent_search.ssl.keystore.password: [password]
```

Comment: The one other wrinkle I encountered was needing to specify the `enterprise-search.yml` and `env.sh` as ConfigMap objects in our Kubernetes cluster. The Docker container tries to create those files, and didn't play well when I specified the options as environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a n/w issue, Also thing which I want to highlight is that **You service is running fine locally as shown in curl command but maybe its not exposed outside localhost, hence your Enterprise search is not able to connect it**, can you try include below config to your ES and restart it.

`network.host:0.0.0.0` this will bind it to all n/w interfaces and detailed explaination can be found on [official docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html)

Comment: That could definitely have been it! It's not, however. That `monitoring.internal` hostname is the load balancer for a fairly large cluster that we're using for all of our other log collection, so it really ought to be available whether that's called by the service or with curl. 

Comment: @josephkibe, but can you ping this from your other servers and esp from Enetreprise search servers, make sure there is network connection b/w these two

Comment: If I understand correctly, yes, that hostname is accessible. There are hundreds of services on dozens of servers (Filebeat, etc) going to the `monitoring.internal` hostname. That's what I was double-checking with the curl command. I ran that from the instance where I'm trying to set up the Enterprise Search service. The problem is the Enterprise Search service getting to Elasticsearch, not other services getting to the Enterprise Search instance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue w/ enterprise-search+ES 7.10.0 running in a docker container. The [accepted solution outlined above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64051320/3942015) is excellent and got me most of the way, however the generated outfile.key kept puking at startup with:

> enterprisesearch_1  | LoadError: load error: /usr/share/enterprise-search/lib/war/config/application -- java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DLApplicationSpecific cannot be cast to org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence

The solution was, when generating my outfile.key, to strip the "Bag attributes" stuff out the .key file. So instead of the original command of:

> openssl pkcs12 -in elasticsearch-certificates.p12 -out outfile.key -nodes -nocerts

I instead did (my p12 file has a password which requires the "-passin pass:my_password" portion):

> openssl pkcs12 -in elasticsearch-certificates.p12  -nodes -nocerts -passin pass:my_password | openssl rsa -out outfile.key

And that was it.